# Grammar highlight using VIM is unreadable

Tags: vim

I enjoy the `SpellBad` highlight that I have, it makes sense.  What's the magic way of adjusting the grammar portion of it?

Here's my .vimrc

```
set spell spelllang=en_us
hi clear SpellBad
hi SpellBad cterm=underline ctermfg=red
```

[image: ugly highlight]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `vim` doesn't do grammar checks.  It says this explicitly on, e.g. line 32 of `/usr/share/vim/vim82/doc/spell.txt` (this file may be in a different location on your system, depending on your distro and installed version of vim.  or just type `:help spell` in `vim`)

   ```
    Vim only checks words for spelling, there is no grammar check.
   ```
2. AFAICT from looking closely at that awful white on cyan text, it seems to be a capitalisation problem ("this" should be capitalised as "This").  Try adding the following to your `.vimrc`:

   ```
    hi SpellCap cterm=underline ctermfg=red
   ```

BTW, that same `spell.txt` file says:

```
The words that are not recognized are highlighted with one of these:
    SpellBad    word not recognized                 |hl-SpellBad|
    SpellCap    word not capitalised                |hl-SpellCap|
    SpellRare   rare word                           |hl-SpellRare|
    SpellLocal  wrong spelling for selected region  |hl-SpellLocal|
```

Comment: BTW, if you want actual grammar checking in vim, apparently there's a plugin called `grammarous` to do that.  I've never used it so don't know if it's any good, but you can find it at https://github.com/rhysd/vim-grammarous - it looks like it uses [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/), which requires Java.